# How to output values from a dictionary without printing it out as a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was a assigned to group ana grams together lexiographicaly.

Below is one of the test cases:

*Input:* 
`eat tea tan ate nat bat`

*Output:*

`ate eat tea
 bat
 nat tan`

However, I keep getting the following output where the the anagrams are encapsulated in the list and the order at which each line gets printed varies every time:

`['ate', 'eat', 'tea']
 ['nat', 'tan']
 ['bat']`
 
or

`['nat', 'tan']
 ['bat']
 ['ate', 'eat', 'tea']`

or

`['ate', 'eat', 'tea']
 ['bat']
 ['nat', 'tan']`

How do I fix this so that it outputs without being capped in a list and possibly in the right order?

This is what i have done so far:

```
import sys
from collections import *
def ComputeAnagrams(string):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word in string:
        key = ''.join(sorted(word))
        d[key].append(word)
    return d

def main():
    for string in sys.stdin:
        stringList = string.split()
        if len(stringList) == 0:
            break
        d = ComputeAnagrams(stringList)
        for key,anagrams in d.items():
            if len(anagrams) >=1:
                print(sorted(anagrams))
        print ('')
main()
```

Note: the machine that runs this programs reads input from stdin/keyboard and prints the output to console(stdout).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `key = ''.join(sorted(word))` ? To get the items of a dictionary in order, use an [OrderedDict](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is -

```
print(sorted(''.join(anagrams)))
```

You are using `sorted` after join the list to a string, in that case, sorted returns a list of characters in the sorted order (I guess that is the current output you are getting).

If you want the elements in sorted order, sorted should be used on `anagrams` list, not the string after joining. Example -

```
print(', '.join(sorted(anagrams)))
```

I am also using `', '` to join the strings, so as to use `,` as the separator, otherwise the output would be all strings together without any spaces in-between, if you want, you can use any other separator you want.

Demo -

After above change -

Input -

```
eat tea tan ate nat bat
```

Output -

```
bat
ate, eat, tea
nat, tan
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on how to remove the comma?

Comment: Like I said in the answer you can use a different separator, even space if you want to. Try - `print(' '.join(sorted(anagrams)))`